# Randomizing function, etc. locations for shared libs

Tags: gcc, linker, ln

Currently, when I create a shared library, functions from within the same object files like to lie together. Is there a good solution (that does not involve splitting up source files) to try and spread function locations apart? We are currently using a cross-compiled, 4.2.1 version of gcc and the gnu tools.

Comment: As horrible as it sounds, security. Licensing issues, etc. I'd rather not clue an attacker in that functions A, B, and C which are right next to each other are all related.

I know, it's a terrible reason, and it won't really do a lot, but even a little bit can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can do what you want using GNU-ld linker script (if you are on platform for which GNU ld works), you can't do it portably.

In addition, it's a totally wasted effort: any hacker worth their salt will not care about moving functions around. If you really want to make it hard*er* to reverse engineer your code (or just bypass your license scheme), you should use much stronger techniques, described e.g. [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886411794).

[Arguably](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.728133.14), that's still totally wasted effort.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the arguments that fighting crackers is a losing battle. That said, some of the push for this is management driven, not developer driven.

Comment: Can you do it without putting entries in the linker script for every function? C++ has a lot of generated functions from template instantiations making that impractical for even small code bases. I have non-crack/hack proofing reason for wanting to randomize function locations.

Comment: @JosephGarvin I don't see why C vs C++ matters: there are likely too many functions to assign manually either way. So you run a normal link, then `nm a.out` to find all the relevant functions, then `sort -R` to randomize their order and generate a linker script, and finally a second link using the generated linker script, to produce randomized binary.

Comment: @EmployedRussian oh, can I take an existing binary and run the linker script on it and have it rearrange it, or do you mean I do a new fresh link?

Comment: @JosephGarvin I mean a fresh new link, using the same compiled object files. You could also skip the first link if you know all the objects selected into the link (but this is rare).